# replace column values with values from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

df1

```
     Home  Place
a    MS    Z2
c    KM    Z3
d    RR    R2
```

df2

```
     Place1
a    A2      
c    A66
z    F32
x    K41
t    E90
```

I want to replace values of df2['Place1'] with df1['Place'] when indexes are matching and leave it the same when indexes are not matching.

Desired result:

```
     Place1
a    Z2 
c    Z3
z    F32
x    K41
t    E90
```

I tried to use pd.replace but it returns NAs

Answer (score 1):

Try with `update`

```
df2['Place1'].update(df1['Place'])
df2
Out[75]: 
  Place1
a     Z2
c     Z3
z    F32
x    K41
t    E90
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I got this error:
"Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

```
df2['Place1'] = df2['Place1'].update(df1['Place'])
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I got this error: "Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories"

Comment: I didn't know that you have categorical columns, then you would have to set the same categories for both first. When you turn it into a Categorical, you can specify the categories.